# Ubuntu on external hard drive | graphic drivers problem

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, ati

First of all :i'm a unfamiliar when it comes to ubuntu or any other linux distros..

**Question backround:** I installed ubuntu 12.10 on my external hard drive. (Desktop PC) Installed closed amd drives because default ones freeze "desktop" view.

Now i plugged external hard drive on my laptop and it says that **there is a problem with graphic drivers.**

Laptop graphic card= Nvidia GT 555m,

Desktop PC graphic gard = AMD Radeon HD 6950

**Question:** Is there some way that i don't have to reinstall graphic drivers everytime when i plug hard drive into different machine. "Just Select it."

Comment: I don't believe there is a easy way. try `sudo rmmod radeon` & `sudo rmmod radeonhd`,to remove radeon driver. more over your laptop GPU is probably optimus enabled. Avoid installing nvidia drivers directly.

Comment: I know this is a little late. When you made the image for the Ubuntu 12.10, did you enable the "persistence" option? This lets you save the configurations.

Comment: It may be possible to have grub setup the display drivers with two different menu options one for desktop the other for laptop.